# Resize Landscape Images of varying sizes to fit fixed portrait with circle frame

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

I have dozens of landscape images of varying sizes: 522 x  393, 496 x 473, 428 x 336, 359 x 240....etc etc.

I want to display them in a portrait frame (300 x 340) with a circular crop (that becomes a circle border on hover). The inspiration [is from here](https://360i.com/about/):

[image]
[image]

However, there is no consistent dimensions among my images. One of the big issues I'm running into is that on hover over some boxes, the name and title appears over the image. But on some images that are not tall enough, the name and title appear over black (the default background of the element holding the image). If I push my too small images all the way down such that the name/title always appears on top of the photo, the face is usually out of the circle crop. I don't know hot to resize my photos so that:

1. the background of the name and title is consistent on hover (either the photo background or black filler background)
2. The face is inside the circle crop.

[View my js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mzechar/vr0yoL7x/10/)
HTML:

```
<div class="team-listing">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/nkzsc7n9d/Aman.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/nkzsc7uz5/CCK.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/6x8a9vktt/Yin.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/5i6pl19f5/Emma.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/jomgge2bl/Yu-_Wei.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/gujb2tptt/Gaurav.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/fs94k8wpt/Guangyu.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/ubg9lo5a9/Ila.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/a42ttdn8h/Ivy.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/3qdqq3v75/Jacky.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/6kgw3kcsx/Jian.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/4fwj2idr5/Joseph.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/hwthldgcx/Neeraj.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/7mr2m5lch/Paul.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/n88e6450h/Peiti.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/8djssdqf5/image.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/sjnaqx6jl/Yu.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/3qdqq6v81/Priyank.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/55fbewold/Qi.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/oaikorb01/Sean.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/4354wfaxt/Yi.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/daxdd2zzl/Steve.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/yxcdu4dzl/Vinay.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/vqhuahltt/Vincent.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/agu7zo0e9/Wei.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/4fwj2l629/Weikang.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/atlm5u38h/Wei_An.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <svg width="0" height="0">
          <clipPath id="circle">
              <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </clipPath>
      </svg>
            <a href="#">
              <article>
                <svg class="portrait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <!-- no automatic sizing for SVG image, width and height must be set -->
              <image width="300" height="340" x="0" y="-20" xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.cc/epyy1v68h/Wenxin.jpg.jpg"></image>
              <circle class="ring" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"></circle>
          </svg>
                <div class="bio">
                  <h2>Chun-Kang Chen</h2>
                  <h4>Article Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: The main issue will be the location of the circle. If you don't know the size of the image you can't positon the circle in the appropriate point. Consistent image sizes would be the optimal issue and there is **nothing** programatically that can tell you to focal point of an unknown image. Essentially... **this is impossible**.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulie_D mentioned, the best (and ofttimes standard) case is that you crop the photos to have consistent and similar placement of the faces, this would effectively solve both of your issues in one fell swoop. Barring that, however:

Positioning the text would be relatively straight forward with some creative positioning based on the circle and using some an overflow container. But your big issue is the face as the focal point. There are some facial recognition API's that would let your find the approximate center of a face, such as [Face-API.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) and [Tracking.js](https://trackingjs.com/examples/face_hello_world.html). These would allow you to position the image relatively behind the circle mask, anchored to the center of their face.

However, you can see where this is asking for trouble. Any faces it doesn't recognize need a fallback or an override, not to mention learning a new library (which isn't necessarily a *bad* thing I suppose).

Honestly for only having 26 photos, you'd probably be better off and get more consistent results if you just took the 5 minutes to crop them.